# install 22.04: Fail to boot after Grub menu

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, bootloader, initramfs

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22 (actually Ubuntu-studio, I don't think that makes a difference)
on a a brand new Beelink computer from an ISO copied on a usb stick.

The computer came preinstalled with W11 (to my surprise, as it wasn't advertized as such), and I had already a hard time managing to boot
from USB stick.
I now have a bootable USB stick (made with Unetbootin) and I am able to boot from it.

So I get to the Grub (2.06) menu, select "Try or Install UbuntuStudio".
Next, after a couple of seconds, I get this screen (sorry for low quality):

[image]

Seems like a failure of `initramfs`

I now have a Busybox v1.30.1 shell, `$ uname -a` says it's a
5.19.0 kernel, but I don't know what I can do next.

As the message says

> file does not fit into a 512-byte sector

I checked (with `ls -l`):
the file `/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs` is... 4,294,967,295 bytes!
(so no wonder it does not fit!)

I read several similar posts on this, but no success

Could this issue be somewhat related to the infamous 4GB limit of FAT32 (my USB stick is indeed formated  with FAT32)? But I always though that was mandatory to build bootable sticks.

### Additional info:

- computer has a 500GB drive, and a AMD Ryzen 7 5800H
- I did check the iso hash, was fine (with `sha256sum`)
- Some posts suggest to set SATA mode from IDE to AHCI.
  Unfortunately, in the bios menu, I indeed have a "SATA configuration", but it is empty, no settings to change!
- BIOS: American Megatrends
- APTIO version 2.22.1282

#### Edit 2023-06-22

I tried same USB drive on another computer: I was able to boot on it, but after selecting the "try or install" choice: exact same issue.
So I believe it is not a hardware issue. I will try another USB drive.

Comment: I just tried formatting the USB stick partition using ext4 and exFAT: no success, the computer doest boot on it and switches directly to Windows...